# How to separate css rules for files in react?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, css-specificity

I am working on two pages in reactjs. One is a landing page and the other is an articles page. The problem I am having is the CSS rules for the landing page are affecting the appearance of the articles page. I think this has to do with reactjs since it bundles all CSS files into one. How do I separate the CSS rules for each page so that the CSS rules of one page do not affect the appearance of another?

Comment: Just a suggestions, but back when I used react, I used [styled components](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components) with scoped styles. Personally I like the approach of having a single file with all the information for the component

Comment: This problem has **nothing** to do with React and it seems you do not yet know how to construct CSS in general for web pages. you need to wrap all the CSS rules for a certain page under a "father" rule so they will be encapsulated. this is easier with *SCSS* or automatic with `styled-components`. I would suggest giving each page a different class to its wrapper element, like `div class="page--home"` and so on, then use that class as prefix for all that page's rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

give unique class/id to body or make a wrapping div for each page like

`<body class="landing-page"> or <div class="landing-page">` 
and
 `<body class="article-page"> or <div class="article-page">`

then write css like:

```
.lanading-page .your-selector{
    cssrules
}
```

Other options:

- [Unique Pages, Unique CSS Files](https://css-tricks.com/unique-pages-unique-css-files/)
- [ID Your Body For Greater CSS Control and Specificity](https://css-tricks.com/id-your-body-for-greater-css-control-and-specificity/)

Answer (score 0):

I personally think the easiest way is to write css in js. There is no need to separate css from js. Just write them together.
For example,

```
const newComponent=props=>{
   <div style={{ display: "flex", alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center" }}>
     <button type="primary">Confirm</button>
     <button type="primary">Cancel</button>
   </div>
}
```

You can also refer to a third library, radium, which helps you write more advanced css. https://formidable.com/open-source/radium/

If you are going to learn react native in the future, you will find out that all css is written in js.
I hope that this helps.